# How can I make dateplot x-ticks steps to 4 years?

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I'm currently trying to create a nice election diagram for Bavaria. This is what I got by now:

[image]

### LaTeX source

Complete source with Makefile and data is [on Github](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/tikz/landtagswahlen-in-bayern). Here is the LaTeX-part without csv-file:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=false, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %layout

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            date coordinates in=x,
            xticklabel={\year},
            x tick label style={align=center, rotate=45},
            yticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\,\%,
            date ZERO=1946-06-30,
            xmin={1946-01-01},
            xmax={2010-01-01},
            extra y ticks={5},
            /pgfplots/ytick={0,10,...,100},
            ymin=0, ymax=100,
            width=15cm, height=8cm,     % size of the image
            grid = major,
            grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            legend style={at={(1.15,1)}, anchor=north}
         ]
          \addplot[blue, dashed, mark=triangle*] table [x=Wahltag, y=Wahlbeteiligung, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
          \addplot[black,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=CSU, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
          \addplot[red,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=SPD, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
          \addplot[green,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=GRÜNE, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
          \addplot[yellow,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=FDP, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
          \legend{Wahlbeteiligung,CSU,SPD,Grüne,FDP}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Questions

How can I make 4-year steps for x ticks?

Can I make one label for every year in the csv-file?

Comment: Can you replace one of the csv files with an inline table with a few entries?

Comment: I don't understand your second question sorry..

Comment: Try xtick=data,

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `xtick=data` is exactly what I was looking for! Now it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/C1Q9JHY.png - the only problem is that it makes xticks for `1946` twice, because there were twice elections (this is quite unlikely to happen ever again, but now I have to deal with it). Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Red: John Kormylo provided me the solution to what I thought of. What would have been a better way to ask for it?

Comment: No easy ones.  You could list all the years manually: xtick = {1946,1950, etc.}

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: What, and do all the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was never able to get pgfplot to handle the file I copied from his web site, so I just commented out that part of the code.

[image: pgfplot]

```
\documentclass[varwidth=false, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %layout

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            date coordinates in=x,
            xticklabel={\year},
            x tick label style={align=center, rotate=45},
            yticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\,\%,
            date ZERO=1946-06-30,
            xtick={1946-01-01,1950-01-01,1954-01-01,1958-01-01,1962-01-01,1966-01-01,1970-01-01,1974-01-01,
                       1978-01-01,1982-01-01,1986-01-01,1990-01-01,1994-01-01,1998-01-01,2002-01-01,2006-01-01,2010-01-01},
            xmin={1946-01-01},
            xmax={2010-01-01},
            extra y ticks={5},
            /pgfplots/ytick={0,10,...,100},
            ymin=0, ymax=100,
            width=15cm, height=8cm,     % size of the image
            grid = major,
            grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            legend style={at={(1.15,1)}, anchor=north}
         ]
%    \addplot[blue, dashed, mark=triangle*] table [x=Wahltag, y=Wahlbeteiligung, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
%    \addplot[black,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=CSU, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
%    \addplot[red,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=SPD, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
%    \addplot[green,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=GRÜNE, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
%    \addplot[yellow,mark=square*] table [x=Wahltag, y=FDP, col sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};
%    \legend{Wahlbeteiligung,CSU,SPD,Grüne,FDP}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: error messages follow:

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}).

PGFPlots: reading {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv}
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.32 ...sep=comma] {landtagswahlen-in-bayern.csv};


The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Can you please tell me which error you've got? I've just tested it with `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)` and it worked fine.

Comment: @moose - I added the error messages to my answer (for clarity).  It repeated several times.  I just loaded pgfplots today (I'm switching from XP to Win 7).

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem, but I couldn't :-/

Comment: @moose - I suspect it either has something to do with the OS or the fact that I copied the file by cut and pasting the text itself.

Comment: Hmm ... probably the umlaut (`ü` in `Grüne` and `Ö` in `ÖDP`) got broken. Or a problem with `\n` and `\r\n` line breaks. Do you have line breaks in the CSV file?

Comment: @moose - Nope.  OTOH, I didn't know the umlauts were ASCII (UTF8).  Anyway, it's not your problem.

Comment: I've just seen that the CSV file was mal formed (too many `,` in one line). I've corrected it.